# Erro ao salvar registros no banco

Tags: php, mysql, formulário

Tenho um formulário normal com uma página normal pra importar as informações pra uma tabela normal do banco, mas por algum motivo cai direto no die e não salva as informações.

Formulário:

```
<form method="POST" action="update-cli.php">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="NOME">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NOME" name="NOME" placeholder="Nome do cliente">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="DATA">Data de nascimento:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DATA" name="DATA" placeholder="Data de Nascimento do cliente">
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ENDERECO">Endereço:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ENDERECO" name="ENDERECO" placeholder="Endereço do consultório">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="TELEFONE">Telefone:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TELEFONE" name="TELEFONE" placeholder="Telefone fixo">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="CELULAR">Celular:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CELULAR" name="CELULAR" placeholder="Telefone celular">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Página de import:

```
<?php

    $nome = $_POST['NOME'];
    $data = $_POST['DATA'];
    $endereco = $_POST['ENDERECO'];
    $telefone = $_POST['TELEFONE'];
    $celular = $_POST['CELULAR'];

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'sis_tam') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('$nome', '$data', '$endereco', '$telefone', '$celular')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

?>
```

Tabela no banco:

> ID NOME DATA ENDERECO TELEFONE CELULAR

Alguém pode me apontar o problema? Obrigada

Estrutura do banco:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que erro está sendo mostrado?

Comment: Os dados de conexão com o banco de dados estão corretos?

Comment: Como está a estrutura sql da tabela no banco de dados?

Comment: O erro que dá é "Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro", aquele que eu coloquei no "or die".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código `SQL`está gerando o erro 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Isso acontece porque sua tabela possui 6 colunas e você está passando 5, por mais que o `ID` seja auto-incremento, você precisa especificar em quais colunas você vai gravar os dados, seu `$sql` deve ficar assim

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (NOME, DATA, ENDERECO, TELEFONE, CELULAR) VALUES ('$nome', '$data', '$endereco', '$telefone', '$celular')";
```

Para descobrir esse tipo de erro a maneira mais fácil e dar um `echo` na sua variável `$sql` e executar o código gerado direto no gerenciador do banco de dados, provavelmente ele vai apontar o erro pra você.

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Eu tinha imaginado que o problema fosse não ter passado o id, mas não sabia como passar se não tinha um campo com o name ID. Obrigada, ajudou demais! :)